# Jackson JSON & Jayway JSON Path

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonpath

I have a json string as below

```
    {
     "haserrors": 
                 {
                   "errornumber": "400",
                   "errors": [
                               {
                                 "nameofbusiness-error-1": "nameofbusiness must have a length greater than 1",
                                 "nameofbusiness-error-2": "legalname must have a length greater than 1",
                                 "nameofbusiness-error-3": "postaladdress must have a length greater than 1",
                                 "nameofbusiness-error-4": "city must have a length greater than 1",
                                 "nameofbusiness-error-5": "state must have a length greater than 1",
                                 "nameofbusiness-error-6": "pincode must have a length greater than 6, pincode must be numeric, pincode must be positive",
                                 "nameofbusiness-error-7": "fewwords must have a length greater than 1",
                                 "nameofbusiness-error-8": "lob must have a length greater than 1",
                                 "nameofbusiness-error-9": "step must be numeric, step must be positive"
                              }
                            ]
                }
    }
```

I need to extract all nodes and values under "errors". This is my current piece of code

```
    Configuration conf = Configuration.builder().jsonProvider(new JacksonJsonNodeJsonProvider())
            .options(Option.ALWAYS_RETURN_LIST, Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS).build();
    ArrayNode jsonErrorMessageNodes = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(<<JSON STRING ABOVE>>).read("$..errors");

  for (Iterator<JsonNode> it = jsonErrorMessageNodes.elements() ; it.hasNext() ; ) {
            JsonNode node = it.next();
            String s = node.toString();
            System.out.println(node);
        }
```

How do I get the node name?

Comment: What is the issue that you face with the existing `piece of code`?

Comment: How do I get the node name?

Comment: Re this: "How do I get the node name?" are you referring to "haserrors"?, "errors"? Or are you referring to the name of the error e.g.  "nameofbusiness-error-1", "nameofbusiness-error-2" etc?

Comment: @glytching - Yes, I was looking to get the node names  "nameofbusiness-error-1", "nameofbusiness-error-2"  and so on. Thanks much for the timely help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code ...

```
Configuration conf = Configuration.builder().jsonProvider(new JacksonJsonNodeJsonProvider())
        .options(Option.ALWAYS_RETURN_LIST, Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS).build();
ArrayNode jsonErrorMessageNodes = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(json).read("$..errors[*]");

for (Iterator<JsonNode> it = jsonErrorMessageNodes.elements() ; it.hasNext() ; ) {
    JsonNode node = it.next();
    for (Iterator<String> it1 = node.fieldNames(); it1.hasNext(); ) {
        final String s = it1.next();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

... will print out:

```
nameofbusiness-error-1
nameofbusiness-error-2
nameofbusiness-error-3
nameofbusiness-error-4
nameofbusiness-error-5
nameofbusiness-error-6
nameofbusiness-error-7
nameofbusiness-error-8
nameofbusiness-error-9
```

The key difference between this and the code you posted is the JsonPath expression. You were using: `$..errors` which produces something like:

```
[
   null,
   [
      {...}
   ],
   null
]
```

So, there's more than one node to walk through in order to find the one of interest to you, By contrast, this expression: returns **only** the `errors` array e.g.

```
[
   {...}
]
```

Comment: Noted your comments. Much appreciated. Thank you!